# Same records being added on unique constraints

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-migrations, unique-constraint

I have added a unique together (badge_id, speech_id, badge_type) however I can still add data with same information, Attaching my schema as well
[image]

I can explain one thing.
unique constrain was applied and those column relation was `DO_NOTHING` and then in next migrations I updated it to `CASCADE` not sure if that is causing this misleading behavior of adding same rows.

I double check if my django migrations were successful by extracting schema info from mysql, attached image.

Comment: *however I can still add data with same information* One of the columns contains NULLs. Remember - any NULLs differs from each other! they are unique, none NULL is equal another NULL. So your rows are unique by specified columns set.

Comment: For `NULL` that does not count, since `NULL` is considered different form `NULL`. Can you share the model, since that can be fixed.

Comment: Thankyou Akina and willeM_ Van Onsem the issue was with this NULL, other than NULL values the constrain is working fine.